# How to get ForeignKey field value during new model creation?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm looking for the most efficient way to implement this kind of mechanism in Django model.
Let's assume a situation, where there are 2 very simple models:

```
class FKModel(models.Model):
    value = BooleanField()

class AModel(models.Model):
    fk = models.ForeignKey(FKModel)
    a_value = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # the line below is incorrect
        if not self.fk.value:    # <--- how to do this in a proper way?
            raise ValidationError('FKModel value is False')
        super(AModel, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super(AModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I know, that I can do somethink like `FKModel.objects.all()/.get()`, but I don't think it is the best solution (as it requires additional requests to database).

Comment: Well you will need to do an extra request to the database anyway (unless `fk` has already been fetched).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you try to do in your `clean()` method, but I assume you are trying to constrain a not null condition for the foreign key. All fields are not null constrained by default, and you have to set `null=False` and `blank=False` if you want the field to accept nulls:

```
class AModel(models.Model):
    fk = models.ForeignKey(FKModel, null=True, blank=True)
    a_value = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

If you want to constrain a not null condition for a field by hand, you should do it like this:

```
class FKModel(models.Model):
    value = BooleanField()

class AModel(models.Model):
    fk = models.ForeignKey(FKModel)
    a_value = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # the line below is correct
        if self.fk is None:    # <--- this is the proper way?
            raise ValidationError('FKModel value is False')
        super(AModel, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super(AModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

For retrieving database records and its related records, you use **prefetch_related**, and you get your record and its related records in one single database hit:

```
AModel.objects.all().prefetch_related('fk')
```